# Finding the limit of the recursive sequence defined as $5a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}+2a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, geometric-progressions, telescopic-series

> Find the limit of the recursive sequence defined as follows: $$5a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}+2a_n\;\;\text{for $n\geq 0$, $a_1=1/2$  and $a_2=2/3$}.$$

Could someone give me a hint as to how to start this problem? I think it is increasing.

Comment: We need $a_1$ and $a_2$ !

Comment: How do you *prove* a number?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [second-order homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) whose characteristic polynomial is
$$5z^2-3z-2=5(z+2/5)(z-1).$$
Hence the general solution is 
$$a_n=A(-2/5)^n+B$$
where the constants $A$ and $B$  depend on the initial terms $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Are you able to find the limit of $a_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity given $a_1=1/2$  and $a_2=2/3$?

Answer (score 1):

$$5a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}=2a_{n}-2a_{n+1}$$ or
$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=-\frac{2}{5}(a_{n+1}-a_n),$$
which says that $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$ is a geometric progression.

Thus, $$a_{n+1}-a_n=(a_2-a_1)\left(-\frac{2}{5}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{6}\left(-\frac{2}{5}\right)^{n-1}.$$
Thus, $$a_n=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(-\frac{2}{5}\right)^{k-1}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{\left(-\frac{2}{5}\right)^{n-1}-1}{-\frac{2}{5}-1}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{-1}{-\frac{2}{5}-1}=\frac{13}{21}.$$